# how to check i'm using MPTCP

Tags: mptcp

I have tried that website to check that is I'm using MPTCP but it didn't work. but in Wireshark, I can see that there are some entries of MPTCP. but only on eth1. I have attached the picture. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryRPD.png)

is my system is using mptcp or not?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending SYNs with MPTCP so your machine looks ok but your syn are retransmitted so it doesn't seem like you receive an answer from the website. Try with http://amiusingmptcp.de/